# MS WORD. How to create link to a picture within the same document?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

I had picture in document somewhere on page 2-3 inserted via MS WORD menu, and I want to crate a hyperlink in next pages to this picture, like for content table item or other place in document.

How to to it for picture?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I found it: 
MS Word main menu (ribbon) > Insert > Links > Cross-refference
From selected dialog chose "figure" options in "Reference type", chose other options, desired picture and click "Insert" button, then close dialog (or click "Cancel" button).

[image: Insert cross reference to a figure within the same document]